# Is {background:0;} valid CSS?

Tags: css, background, shorthand

I understand that `background` is the shorthand property - what will the value `0` do to all of the properties and is it valid CSS?

```
selector {background:0;}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background it will work but I never seen anyone use it like that

Comment: It is `background: none` not `background:0`

Comment: @kougiland: No, that means something different, i.e. `background-image: none` instead of `background-position: 0`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`background:0` is valid css and gets compiled into:

```
background-image: initial;
background-position-x: 0px;
background-position-y: 50%;
background-size: initial;
background-repeat-x: initial;
background-repeat-y: initial;
background-attachment: initial;
background-origin: initial;
background-clip: initial;
background-color: initial;
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the zero will be interpreted as the horizontal background position. The other background properties are set to the default values, so you end up with the same as:

```
background-image: none;
background-repeat: repeat;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-position: 0 center;
background-color: transparent;
```